# An indication of whether the user is still on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for an event that will return when close page whether the user is connected to my site.
`onbeforeunload` does not help me because it is also activated in efresh, submit, browse from page to page on the same site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client side event that triggers when a user leaves your site for another site specifically.

If you want to know if users are online you can make repeated ajax calls on a timer, and use a server side session that updates a timestamp of the last request. Using this you can query the timestamps for example, get sessions where the timestamp is in the last 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If polling is an option and you have a server-side backend, you could make a keep-alive script polling the server every x seconds and add it to all pages on your site. If you do not receive enough calls (i suggest at least 3 or so), consider it as a signal the user has logged out. Of course this won't provide an immediate feedback, but should be reliable enough.